# SQL Nvarchar(max) not working as intended

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, odbc

I've come across something that doesn't quite make sense. I noticed a weird occurrence that happens when you try to return data from a SQL Server database to PHP. If you use the SQL Sever Native Client driver in PHP, NVARCHAR(MAX) is supposed to be returned as a stream type according to articles online. In SQL Server Management Studio if I create a new table with these datatypes the nvarchar(max) field is returned as a stream:

```
[PK][int]
[nvarchar(255)]
[nvarchar(max)]
```

If I create a table using these datatypes then nvarchar(max) is returned as its actual value and not a stream.

```
[PK][int]
[nvarchar(256)]
[nvarchar(max)]
```

I saw somewhere that you cannot use nvarchar(max) correctly with PHP if you don't say to use the SQL Native Client driver, however I do have it coded in to use it. This is being performed using SQL Server 2005, PHP 5.3, both on Windows Server 2003.

Can anyone explain why I can get the actual value of nvarchar(max) in one table and not the other?

I don't need to know how to work around it, I'm using NVARCHAR(4000) for my tables anyway, I just want to know why NARCHAR(256) allows NVARCHAR(MAX) to work even though it's not supposed to work according to what I've seen online.

EDIT:

Here's the basic PHP code I use and change to access a use a stored parameter:

```
<?php
$user = "usercm";
$pass ="cmuserpassword";

try{$conn = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=EXAMPLE;DATABASE=EXAMPLE;",$user,$pass);}
catch(PDOException $e){echo "Connection Failed";}

if($conn)
{
    $uspGetAll = $conn->prepare("{CALL uspGetPowerDetails()}");
    if($uspGetAll->execute())
      {
          $results = $uspGetAll->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $_SESSION['testExample'] = $results;
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

I don't want to know about other drivers, I just want to know why a different field that is declared as 256 or above changes whether an nvarchar(MAX) is returned as a stream or not.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what your DBMS is. I've assumed SQL Server and re-tagged accordingly—feel free to correct it if I'm wrong.

Comment: yeah it's SQL Server, just added that in. I had originally mentioned it but accidently deleted it when I deleted a section of my question that wasn't needed.

Comment: Needs more info. What is being displayed? What's the desired output?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the desired output is, this happens on any type of table created, an [NVARCHAR(MAX)] field will always be returned incorrectly unless you have [NVARCHAR(256)] field accompanying it. The value that gets returned without using [NVARCHAR(256)] is a 'stream' I believe though. The thing is it's technically not supposed to work in both situations but [NVARCHAR(256)] allows it though for some reason.

Comment: We need to see the code that you're using that's causing this behavior.

Comment: I added the PHP code which will show that I used PDO ODBC with the SQL Server Native Client driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect two issues might be at fault — take this with a fistful of salt, because I haven't touched a Windows box in aeons.

One issue might, I think, be your use of the PDO_ODBC driver. It's meant to be compatible with DB2 and such, so I see little odds for it to return a stream on a large varchar. In the name of being db engine agnostic and consistent, basically. You might be a bit luckier by using the PDO_SQLSRV driver instead, but this brings me to…

The other problem might be your use of `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. To the best of my knowledge, this will make you fetch the entire value of your field. I'm suspicious that PDO would behave very differently from a DB engine to the next — db engine agnostic and consistent, yada yada.

And sure enough, PDO_Postgres (which I'm more familiar with) will behave like your `nvarchar(max)` field for large objects, unless you use the [Postgres-specific constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.pgsqllobopen.php) or the shift to using the relevant [`pg_*()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-lo-open.php) functions.

Seeing that there are no analogous constants for PDO_SQLSRV, I'll conclude by suggesting that you'll need to try your luck with the `mssql_*()` functions.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely the PDO_ODBC driver. I ended up finding this anomaly playing around using the ODBC driver as the SQLSRV one is incompatible with Windows Server 2003. It was incredibly odd that different fields affects the results of it. There was an issue raised back in March 2 years ago about PDO_ODBC and ODBC: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54169 . Someone posted a quick fix that is supposed to work for PDO_ODBC, however it doesn't seem like they knew about different fields affecting the outcome. Other sites always just said you couldn't access nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 0):

When I used this code with IIS & MSSQL I found a simular error. Maybe its because its a stream. Every 256 char I got a null char in the text.

`$dsn = "odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=mydb;charset=UTF-8;ClientCharset={UTF-8}";`

`while ($myRow = $result->fetch()) { echo $myRow["rawMessage"]; }`

My solution to this are:

`str_replace(chr(0), "", $myTrap["rawMessage"])`

Even if this is an old post and not exactly same error I post this here is somebody else turn into same problem.